# Android fragment z-index overlay

Tags: java, android, xml, fragment

I have two fragments, one of which I want on top of the other, which occupies the whole screen. How can I do this?

Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:opencv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_relativelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/MainCameraFragment"
        android:name="com.james.skullyhud.main_camera.MainCameraFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" >
    </fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Cheers

Comment: `bringChildToFront` is what you may need.have a look at `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#bringChildToFront(android.view.View)` .let me know if it hepls,I will make it as answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_relativelayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
    </fragment>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/MainCameraFragment"
            android:name="com.james.skullyhud.main_camera.MainCameraFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </fragment>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Doesn't compile, missing a </RelativeLayout>. Not sure where you intend it to be.

Comment: Ah saw your edit, and that's what I tried myself - it works! This is great. For bonus points, any idea how to make the MapFragment appear more transparent?

Comment: @YoungMoney which fragment do you want to make transparent?

Comment: The MapFragment, if possible.

Comment: @YoungMoney-i think we can't make MapFragment background transparent..:)

Comment: An issue for another time then. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

This helps for me:

```
YourFragment.getView().bringToFront();
```

Comment: `YourFragment.getView()` will often return `null`.